# Why is this sum a representation of e?

Tags: real-analysis

We have the sum:

$\sum\nolimits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{n!}$

Why is this sum a representation of $e$ when the sum:

$\sum\nolimits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$

is already a representation of $e$?

For me it seams that the first row is greater then the second.

Comment: I think that $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{(n-1)!}$$ is actually $e$

Comment: Remember that $n!=n\cdot (n-1)!$ implying $\frac{n}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$.  Next, recognize that $0!=1$

Comment: @Raffaele careful with your indices.  You have a $(-1)!$ in your series

Comment: stity's answer is a perfect one, it might help you to think about why you thought the first is greater than the second - formalise this argument and see why it doesn't exactly work.

Comment: Taking the difference leads to more equalities such as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n-1}{n!} = 0$ and $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!(n+2)} = 1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac{n}{n!}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{n}{n!}}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\frac{1}{(n-1)!}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac{1}{n!}}$$

Comment: Your first equality uses $\dfrac{0}{0!} =\dfrac{0}{1} = 0$